# Increase date range Symfony2

Tags: forms, date, symfony, date-range

Hi i have a simple problem but can't find a solution :

I have this

```
->add('dateofBirth', 'date', array (
            'widget' => 'choice',
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            'pattern' => '{{ day }}-{{ month }}-{{ year }',
            'years' => range(1850 , date('Y'))


            ))
```

With this the years go from 1902 to now. It seems like there is a predefined date range. My code works because with a year >1902 it takes it into account. Is it possible to change this?

I found a DateTypeTest class in /vendors with this code :

```
  public function testYearsFor32BitsMachines()
    {
        if (4 !== PHP_INT_SIZE) {
            $this->markTestSkipped(
                'PHP must be compiled in 32 bit mode to run this test');
        }

        $form = $this->factory->create('date', null, array(
            'years' => range(1900, 2040),
        ));

        $view = $form->createView();

        $listChoices = array();
        foreach (range(1902, 2037) as $y) {
            $listChoices[] = new ChoiceView($y, $y, $y);
        }

        $this->assertEquals($listChoices, $view['year']->vars['choices']);
    }
```

And i tried to change the 1902 date, even if touching to the vendors isnt really a good idea. But it didn't change anything. Maybe because i'm in prod ?
Its the only occurence of 1902 i can find in my symfony folder

thx for your help

Comment: this limitaiton is due to php itself as stated [here by symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#input) and [here by PHP](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-changelog)

Comment: @SBH this is if we are using `input` as `timestamp`. Default one is `datetime` which doesn't have such limitations.

Comment: I tried datetime as a field type, without any result. So am i doomed and forced to rewrite my db with integers ?